# how to trace or log from a CFC file

Tags: browser, coldfusion, cfc

Is there a way through the brasiers like firebug or another browser plugin to do traces or log console from a cfc file.

I'm completely new to CF so sorry if this seems like a stupid question.

Comment: Don't know CF much but this project might help http://logbox.riaforge.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [cftrace](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c00.html) tag that will allow you to log output to the console, among other spots in your application and development environment.

```
<cftrace category="init data" type="Information" var="myvartooutput" />
```

Calling this tag will output the relevant content in a few places:

1. The console in ColdFusion Builder, if you are using that IDE
2. In Dreamweaver, the Adobe docs mention a server debug tab/view (I don't use DW, so am not sure)
3. At the end of the request in the debug output
4. In cftrace.log, which is in your log directory (/COLDFUSION/INSTALL/DIR/logs/cftrace.log)

You can also use the tag [cflog](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d0d.html) to write data to one of the standard log files or you may choose to have it write the desired data to a custom log file.

```
<cflog file="customlog" application="no" text="Output #somevar#!" />
```

If "customlog" does not exist, CF will create it for you (in the same location noted above).

Hope that helps!

EDIT: I offered this more of an alternative way to using to Firebug ... if you want the logs/traces but were not necessarily wed to a browser/plug-in.

Answer (score 3):

If you want logs to be visible in the browser ColdFire is your best choice. With it, you can see all of ColdFusion's extended debugging information even on a production site. Unless you have the proper authentication via ColdFire the server won't spit out the extended info.

As @gillesc recommended, you can use LogBox which is extracted from the ColdBox framework. The ColdBox Framework has a debugging mode that allows you to trace messages to the bottom of the page, or, to a separate window. This is useful even on production sites since you can observe the tracer methods from other users.

Finally, you can simply print to the console using `writeDump(var="my log message",output="console")` for quick debugging--or--use the `<cflog>` tag to save log messages to a named log file which you can monitor using tail. For a dead simple solution, you can save the log file to the root of your site and simply press F5 to see the new log entries; however, I do not recommend this practice (unless you are saving credit card information and share that file with me :).

Hope this reply helps.

Aaron

Answer (score 0):

If you've got CF Builder you can actually set up a debugger, but it's terribly slow. Here's the documentation on that: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusionBuilder/Using/WS0ef8c004658c1089-31c11ef1121cdfd6aa0-7fff.html

There's also ColdFire, which is a Firebug add-on. Never used it before but I hear good things: https://github.com/nmische/ColdFire/

Comment: ColdFire is the closest thing to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try ColdFire for firebug extension

http://coldfire.riaforge.org/